# asp mvc 4 passing a long string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have a view containing a form. In the form there is a link which allows the user to view one of the textboxes in a separate tab/window.

My question is how do I retrieve the text from that textbox and pass only that text to a controller?

Currently I have the below code 
(which returns:

> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long

)

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostValuation", "Property", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ....Some data (part of a view model)...
    <a href="@Url.Action("ShowLetter", "Controller", new { letter = "TEXT IN TEXTBOX" })" target="_blank">View as letter</a>
    ....Some data (part of a view model)...
    <input type="submit" value="Pass ...Some data... using a View Model" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ShowLetter(string letter)
{
    ViewBag.Letter = letter;
    return View();
}
```

I understand there is a limit on the length of the string I can pass and after reading suggestions I see I can change the web.config to resolve the max length. But this can potentially be thousands of characters long, so I feel that altering the web.config is not the right solution. Can someone offer a better suggestion please.

Comment: I hope your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535159/passing-a-large-html-string-from-view-to-controller

Comment: You would need a form to post the data, but since you already have a form, that would result in invalid nested forms. Its not clear why you would need to display the same value in another window, but one option might be to display it in a modal dialog in the same view.